# android mapview icons in wrong location when zoomed out

Tags: android, maps, zooming, android-mapview, animated

I'm trying to figure out why my icons are showing up over the ocean when I zoom out of my mapview but when I zoom in the points are correct.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

    //set up test points
    point = new GeoPoint(25982160, -80358564);
    showAnimatedMarker(point, "true");  
    point = new GeoPoint(34023084, -84781697);
    showAnimatedMarker(point, "Test");
    point = new GeoPoint(40759508, -73987061);
    showAnimatedMarker(point, "Yo YO YO");
    point = new GeoPoint(34152852, -118336107);
    showAnimatedMarker(point, "Boom shakalaka");
    point = new GeoPoint(-23564595, -46652759);
    showAnimatedMarker(point, "Testing having a real long name");

    mapController.setZoom(4);
    mapController.animateTo(point);
}

public void showAnimatedMarker(GeoPoint point, String locationName)
{
    //animate the marker
    RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.markerlayout, null);
    final ImageView marker = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker);
    final TextView markerText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.markerText);
    final String locName = locationName;
    marker.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            markerText.setText(locName);
            AnimationDrawable markerImage = (AnimationDrawable)marker.getDrawable();            
            markerImage.start();
        }
    });
    mapView.addView(v, 0, new MapView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, point, MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER));

}
```

Here is 2 pictures that show what I mean, 1 is zoomed out and 1 is zoomed into the California location.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Zoomed In Image]

[image: Zoomed Out Image]

Edited:

Here is my updated code (I didn't include the myOverlays class because it is exactly what Frohnzie posted)

```
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
    MyOverlay testOverlay;

     //set up test points
    point = new GeoPoint(25982160, -80358564);
    //showAnimatedMarker(point, "true");
    testOverlay = new MyOverlay(this,  mapView, point);
    mapOverlays.add(testOverlay);       

    point = new GeoPoint(34023084, -84781697);
    //showAnimatedMarker(point, "Test");
    testOverlay = new MyOverlay(this,  mapView, point);
    mapOverlays.add(testOverlay);   

    point = new GeoPoint(40759508, -73987061);
    //showAnimatedMarker(point, "Yo YO YO");
    testOverlay = new MyOverlay(this,  mapView, point);
    mapOverlays.add(testOverlay);   

    point = new GeoPoint(34152852, -118336107);
    //showAnimatedMarker(point, "Boom shakalaka");
    testOverlay = new MyOverlay(this,  mapView, point);
    mapOverlays.add(testOverlay);   

    point = new GeoPoint(-23564595, -46652759);
    //showAnimatedMarker(point, "Testing having a real long name");
    testOverlay = new MyOverlay(this,  mapView, point);
    mapOverlays.add(testOverlay);   

    mapController.setZoom(4);
    mapController.animateTo(point);
    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Ok I figured out that my textview was pushing the icon to the side, but even with the textview.settext = " "; it's still completely in the wrong location when you zoom out :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the overly feature?  The following overlay will animate a marker on the map.  For multiple markers you could use extend OverlayItem.

```
public class MyOverlay extends Overlay {
  private Drawable mMarker;
  private MapView mMapView;
  private int level;
  private Timer timer;
  Private GeoPoint mGeoPoint;

  public MyOverlay(Context context, MapView mapView, GeoPoint geoPoint) {
    mMapView = mapView;
    mGeoPoint = geoPoint;
    mMarker = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.position_anim);
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        level = (level + 1) % 2;
        mMapView.postInvalidate();
      }
    }, 1000, 1000);
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    Point center = new Point();
    projection.toPixels(mGeoPoint, center);

    int width = mMarker.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int height = mMarker.getIntrinsicHeight();

    mMarker.setLevel(level);
    mMarker.setBounds(center.x - width / 2, center.y - height / 2, center.x + width / 2, center.y + height / 2);
    mMarker.draw(canvas);
  }
}
```

Example marker resource (position_anim.xml):

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />
  <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/image2" />
</level-list>
```

Comment: Hi Frohnzie, thanks for answering, I tried your code exactly as is and the results are the same. However to ensure I did add your code correctly, after each point I call:

testOverlay = new MyOverlay(this,  mapView, point);
mapOverlays.add(testOverlay);

and I call mapView.invalidate after all the points are added. I can see the points and they animate (nice way of doing it by the way) however when you zoom out the points are over the water rather than in the location where they should be.

Comment: In my example the center of the marker is over the location.  You will have to adjust the setBounds parameters.  Maybe you can post updated code.

Comment: I added the updated code above, I'll start playing with the setbounds parameters now

Comment: i'm having no luck trying various bounds, how would you know the best values for it?

Comment: You want the bottom tip of the flag at the point `setBounds(center.x, center.y + height, center.x + width, center.y);` without your drawable it is difficult to tell.

Comment: Thanks alot! My code above works and so does yours. My problem was exactly as you put it, setting the bounds correctly. Since im lazy and didn't want to figure out center.x-width ... I simply used boundcenterbottom and added blank space to the other side of my image so that the marker is dead center. I awarded you the bounty for your patience with me and help! Thanks again